# Is honey elemental nutrition, if not why not?

Tags: gastroenterology, liquids

In elemental drinks liquid nutrition is given to patients with ingredients that do not require eznzyme to break them down or any digestive activity.  To my knowledge honey contains monosachiride sugar and doesn't require any digestion so should give energy without any problem to people.  Why then is honey not used to replace the carbohydrate component of an elemental drink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honey is not appropriate for elemental diet because:

-- It is not sterile (elemental diet for both intravenous or enteric use needs to be sterile).

-- Various types of honey have very [different ratios of sugars](http://www.honey.com/images/downloads/carb.pdf) (Honey.com) including some disaccharides, such as sucrose and maltose, and also some proteins and other ingredients (the exact composition of elemental diet needs to be known).